# What are all characters that the Unicode Other_ID_Start and Other_ID_Continue properties include?

Tags: unicode

While reading about `ID_Start` and `ID_Continue` definitions, I found this: https://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#D1. It says that `ID_Start` includes `Other_ID_Start` and `ID_Continue` includes `Other_ID_Continue`. I'm unable to find the definitions of these other. The document I mentioned says that they're defined by [UAX44](https://unicode.org/reports/tr41/tr41-30.html#UAX44). So for example, I tried to consult Unicode 15 version of UAX44: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-30.html The table 9 (Property Table) only says:

> **Other_ID_Start** Used to maintain backward compatibility of ID_Start.

Other than that, there is no additional information. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Other_ID_Start` and `Other_ID_Continue`, like most binary character properties, are defined in the [PropList.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropList.txt) data file in the Unicode Character Database.

In particular, `Other_ID_Start` includes characters that used to be included in `ID_Start` automatically due to some other property they possessed, but now need to be specified manually because said property value has since changed. For example, U+212E ESTIMATED SYMBOL was originally classified as a letter and all letters are `ID_Start` by default, but later it was reclassified as a symbol and thus *would* have been excluded if it weren’t for the backwards compatibility requirement.

Comment: Useful! I was aware of `UnicodeData.txt`, but not `PropList.txt`.